# How To Convert "created_timestamp" Value To A Valid Date In Python

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitter-oauth

I'm currently working on a Twitter bot that automatically reply messages, I'm doing this by using [tweepy](https://pypi.org/project/tweepy/) (the official python twitter library)

I need to filter messages based on the created time as I don't want to reply same message twice. Now the problem is that the API endpoint returns `created_timestamp` as string representation of positive integers.

Below is an example of data returned as per the [doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/list-events)

```
{
  "next_cursor": "AB345dkfC",
  "events": [
    { "id": "110", "created_timestamp": "1639919665615", ... },
    { "id": "109", "created_timestamp": "1639865141987", ... },
    { "id": "108", "created_timestamp": "1639827437833", ... },
    { "id": "107", "created_timestamp": "1639825389806", ... },
    { "id": "106", "created_timestamp": "1639825389796", ... },
    { "id": "105", "created_timestamp": "1639825389768", ... },
    ...
  ]
}
```

My question is "How do I convert the `created_timestamp` to a valid date using python" ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might play with timestamps on [this resource](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

And in your case could use methods like:

```
timestamp = int('timestamp_string')
datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=None)
date.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

From the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) standard library. But integers after the first line are already well comparable if the task is to distinguish differences between the timestamps.

Comment: I'll update question with the returned timestamp

Comment: Just added a string to integer conversion line, which would be enough for filtering. Also, is the JSON parsing thing is part of the question, @Ruby?